# Creating a global variable

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a basic login in my app. What I want to do is set a "Global" variable as true / false if user is logged in.

I've followed [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables).
So this is my code now:

```
import android.app.Application;

public class GlobalParameters extends Application{
    private boolean loggedIn;

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    return loggedIn;
    }

    public void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
    this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
    }
}
```

And this is on my `onCreate`:

```
GlobalParameters gp = ((GlobalParameters)getApplicationContext());
gp.setLoggedIn(false);
```

But `GlobalParameters gp = ...` throws this exception:

> ClassCastException

I've added this too in my manifest:

```
<application android:name=".GlobalParameters" 
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
   android:label="@string/app_name">
</application>
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: I would rather use shared prefs for storing the login token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.getApplication()` to get the `Application` associated with your `Activity`. But I think in your case, going to the `Application` is a bit overkill. You could just use a static field in a class.

However, if you want the state to be retained when your `Activity` is discarded then you can use `SharedPreferences`, a good guide to get started with those is here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: Static fields in Android do not retain state when an activity is discarded. That is the whole point of the (ugly) solution with the application.

Answer (score 0):

If your variable is just to login and logout, is better you use a static variable and set it true on login and set it false on logout.

```
public static boolean loggedIn;
```

and use it as below:

```
myApplication.loggedIn = true;

myApplication.loggedIn = false;
```